# Using react with mix

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, reactjs

I'm trying to set a react front end in a laravel app.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://blog.tighten.co/adding-react-components-to-a-laravel-app) to just link my react components, but It's not working.

My files are correct, and I don't receive any errors.

this is my **app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Example from './components/Example';
```

I also changed my **webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

here's my **component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Example extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Cool, it's working</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Example;

if (document.getElementById('example')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('example'));
}
```

and I have this line in my **app.blade.php**

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

however my `<div id="example"></div>` is empty and I'm not sure why.

I don't receive any errors when doing `npm run watch` so I'm not sure where to start on this.